# How to identify the platform between facebook app canvas / website using PHP?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cross-platform, identity

How can I check if a user is coming from facebook or directly from the site? I have used this method  `$_REQUEST['signed_request']` but they response only one time.

Your response is highly appreciated for me

```
if(isset($_REQUEST)){
            if(isset($_REQUEST['signed_request'])){
                $this->result = "fb_platform";  
            }else{
                $this->result = "web_platform"; 
            }
}
```

Comment: Can javascript based solutions work for you?

Comment: @complex857 please elaborate

Comment: In the serverside, only the first request is "made" by facebook (in reality it's made from the user's browser, but the parameters set from facebook), the subsequent ones simply links or forms and such inside an iframe, from the serverside this makes no difference. However you can detect if you are in an iframe or not via javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed my code after some Stack Overflow question reviews

```
<script>
//if a user is coming from 
//facebook or directly from the site.

function platformAuthentication(){ 

    var platform = "fb_platform";
    if(window.self === window.top) {
        platform = "web_platform";
        $("#platform_key").val(platform);
        $("#platform_form").submit();
    }else{
        platform = "fb_platform";
        $("#platform_key").val(platform);
        $("#platform_form").submit();
    }

}
setTimeout(platformAuthentication,500);
</script>


</head>
<body>
<!--hidden form for user tracking, 
    if a user is coming from fb/direclty 
    from the site
-->
<form id="platform_form" name="platform_form" method="post" target="iframe_platform" action="url">
<input type="hidden"  id="platform_key" name="platform_key" />
</form>
<iframe id="iframe_platform" name="iframe_platform" src="url">
</iframe>
```